# How preg_match works exactly?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I've wrote a simple function to check if the string I send "should be" valid or not.

```
// this works without problems
function validate_email ($value) {
    return preg_match ("/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/", $value);

}

// this doesn't work
function validate_string ($value) {
    return preg_match ("([^<>?=/\]+)", $value);

}
```

the first function works well, if I send an email to `validate_email` I'm used to retain valid it return me `1` or `0` if not.

`validate_string` should do the same with strings of every kind but without `? = < > / \`. If I check the function it return me 1 in anycase, why?

```
validate_string ("tonino"); // return 1 ok
validate_string ("ton\ino\"); // return 1 why?
validate_string ("ton?asd=3"); // return 1 why?
```

the `^` char inside `([^<>?=/]+)` should mean not the chars after (or not?)

Comment: That email check doesn't work without a problem. It fails to match example@example.museum for starters.

Comment: yes, it validate addresses with an extension no more longer than 4 chars, is .museum a valid extension?

Comment: It is, together with names like ".mobi" or ".xn--0zwm56d":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: together with ".mobi" or whaat? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Besides that `"ton\ino\"` is not a valid string and `[^<>?=/\]+` is not a valid regular expression, you have probably some logical misunderstanding.

Your regular expression `[^<>?=/\\]+` (here corrected) will match if there is at least one character that is not `<`, `>`, `?`, `=`, `/` and `\`. So if there is at least one such character, `preg_match` returns `1`. `ton\ino"` and `ton?asd=3` do both contain at least one such character (the match is in both cases `ton`).

A fix for this is to either use assertions for the start and end of the string (`^` and `$`) to only allow legal characters for the whole string:

```
^[^<>?=/\\]+$
```

Or to use a positive character class `[<>?=/\\]+` to match the illegal characters and negate the returned expression of `preg_match`:

```
function validate_string ($value) {
    return !preg_match("([<>?=/\\\\]+)", $value);
}
```

But it would be certainly better to use a whitelist instead of a blacklist.

Comment: Er... Yours is not a valid regular expression either.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Fixed it.

Comment: I always get in trouble with regexps, thanks for help, I use this expression because it's for urls like last.fm japanese artists, so I shoud insert almost all chars

Answer (score 4):

You aren't matching the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string. So `"ton?asd=3"` matches because the pattern matches `t` (and the rest of the string is irrelevant).

Comment: I believe pattern matches `'ton'` in your example

Comment: Yes, it would match `ton` (since the expression is greedy). The `t` is all that is needed for it to actually match though (although I didn't express that all too well).

Comment: thanks, I try everytime to remember al the regex rules, but I always fail!!

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a meta character, you need to escape it. So it would be

```
return preg_match ("([^<>?=/\\\\]+)", $value);
```

Comment: This regexp is invalid and won't even compile

Comment: @Álvaro Oops - forgetting to escape properly while advising to escape properly: Irony, thy name is...

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_string ($value) {
    return !preg_match('#[<>?=/\\\\]#', $value);
}
```

Comment: A bit of explaination would be nice.

Comment: This may or may not be useful code, but it does not answer the question. Just showing a little piece of code will not help the asker or other readers to understand the problem and its solution.